# read Java doubles from binary file into Python

Tags: java, python, io, binaryfiles, data-conversion

I have several matrices in Java that I would like to transfer to Python as efficiently as possible, without requiring anything but standard libraries on both the Java and Python sides.

Currently I serialize them to file using the writeDouble function to write the entries out one by one, and writeInt to write the dimensions of the matrices. Now I would like to read these matrices back into Python. I can get the integers using struct.unpack, but Java's serialization of doubles does not correspond to an algorithm that struct.unpack can implement.

How can I decode a Java double in the binary format that writeDouble uses? I have trouble even finding a specification for the encoding that writeDouble uses.

Answer (score 2):

You're overengineering it; [`DataOutputStream.writeDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeDouble(double)) and related methods are for manually [serializing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) a Java Object, so it can be re-read as a Java Object.  If all you need is to transfer *data*, you can simply write them out as text (or bytes), then read them back in.  Common formats are [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), [JSON](http://json.org/), [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), and [ProtoBuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

If all you're doing is trying to transfer a list of doubles, you can even just write them out one per line, and read them right back in with Python.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm currently using CSV, but that both takes a lot of time and space to write and a lot of time to read for matrices of the size I'm working with. I'd prefer to be able to read and write more efficiently, hence using writeDouble.

Comment: Why do you think Java serialization would take less time or space to write?  The same data has to be written out.  ProtoBuf is a binary format which might be a little more compact for your use case, but you can't reasonably hope to avoid writing O( n ) numbers.

Comment: Because it does take less time and space: imagine converting each of a 126 million doubles to strings and writing those out, vs dumping them as bytes. Empirically, loading CSV into Python is much slower (reading lines, splitting them, then converting from strings to numbers) than using struct.unpack to load them from binary files. My understanding is that Protobuf requires an external library. I really just want a routine that parses the binary format Java writes out to recover doubles in Python. Failing that, an explicit statement of the algorithm Java uses would be great.

Comment: If the string conversion is your bottleneck, [write it out as bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13071777/113632).  Java serialization has overhead you don't need.  Again, ProtoBuf is a binary format designed for speed.  If CSVs are too slow, use ProtoBuf or another existing binary format, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't want to use external libraries. Further, I haven't experienced writeDouble being slow slow (what overhead is there? other than errorchecking, it looks like that call's only incrementing a counter and outputting raw bytes to file). I found out what Java's doing by googling for the source code of writeDouble: it's calling java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits, and the comments seem helpful enough to figure out how to load back its output and convert to double